# Which shutters are exactly similar to NKS FB/Prontor S?

Tags: shutter

I have been searching for spares for my Yashicaflex, Since NKS shutters are so rare and we cannot find spares for it, what shutters are similar to NKS FB/Prontor S, which is easily available for spares?